# How to get html code generated by php using JSONP from another domain?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

How would i get a html code generated by php script on a different domain. people suggest me to use JSONP. I read a lot of JSONP aticles but all of them only get data in this format:

```
callback({"name" : "Remy","id" : "123"}
```

BUT , my php script generates HTML code not the data as shown above. Normally if i'm on the same domain (the javascript and php scripts) , i will use Ajax to do the job like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'user.php',
    data: 'user_id=user_id', //assuming user_id value was already set.
    success: function(html)
    {
        $('#info').empty().html(html);
    }  
});
```

Now , my javascript is on a different domain than my php script. How would i get the html generated by the php scripts using javascript(jQuery , Ajax JSON???) ?

Or am i missing something in JSONP?

Comment: i was thinking about iframe too but its at the last of my list. i want to learn more about using this technique instead of iframe.

Answer (score 0):

JSONP, as the name implies, is for *JSON*.

What you can do is turn your HTML into valid JSON (just use `json_encode()` in your PHP script, passing it your HTML string) and then load the HTML out of that.

Comment: At the end of your PHP script, instead of outputting the HTML (say, from `$html`), instead output `json_encode($html)` plus the necessary JSONP wrapping.